# Can two threads access same method at once after access of synchronized property?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, thread-safety

I am little puzzled by some situations in my code.

```
private var state by synchronized<PlayerState>(Stopped())

val asStarted get() = state as? Started
val asStopped get() = state as? Stopped

inner class Stopped : PlayerState {
    fun start(bpm: BPM = BPM(), volume: Int? = null) {
        state = Started(bpm, volume)
    }
}
```

Imagine two thread are trying to execute `player.asStopped?.start()`, do I have issue here? Do I need to enter something like this?

```
inner class Stopped : PlayerState {
    @Synchronized
    fun start(bpm: BPM = BPM(), volume: Int? = null) {
        if(state is Started) return
        state = Started(bpm, volume)
    }
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Mutli-threaded code is hard for even smart people to get right.   I think an event thread and coroutines, without all the custom locking, would be a safer idea.

Comment: @duffymo I dont know what you know about hot coroutines are implemented but to me it seem quite hight level library. I am writing perfomance critical midi sequencer applications that have to run very smoothly while using cpu of android  to maximum , any high level abstractions in this part of code is out of question as I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right to be concerned.

**The first version of your code does indeed have a race condition**, as two threads could both create `Started` objects, and then set them. Only one thread can be executing the setter at a time, but the second can enter it as soon as the first leaves.

That may not be a problem here. (The `synchronized` delegate will still prevent any low-level problems with accessing the `state`, such as seeing partially-constructed values. And it looks like there's no other state which needs to be correlated with your `state` property, so it can't get into an inconsistent state.)  But being able to start twice may not be good!

**I don't *think* the second version of your code suffers from any threading issues**, as written. (If it didn't have the `@Synchronized`, then it would indeed have a [time-of-check-to-time-of-use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race condition.)

However, **it's a little confusing because it uses two separate locking mechanisms** (the `@Synchronized` method locks on the `Stopped` object, while the `by synchronized` state has its own lock), and it's hard to follow the way those locks might interact, even in this very simple example.

I also suspect it could lead to race conditions in the surrounding code. Once started, can your player be stopped again? If so, what will the `stop()` method lock on — if it's the `Started` object, then that's yet another lock, and I can see some race conditions there.

So I'd strongly look at refactoring this to use only a single lock.

I don't know the `synchronized` delegate your code is using. If it has some sort of test-and-set, compare-and-swap, or similar function, then you may be able to do what you need using that. Otherwise, it's probably best to drop the delegate and do your own locking, I'm afraid.

This does raise a wider question about the design, though: **why does your `Stopped` class have a `start()` method??** Surely it's the *player* which starts and stops, and the state is just a reflection of that? So changing the state isn't an operation *on* the current state at all.

Addressing that design issue will almost certainly make it easier to fix the locking too.

Comment: There is one detail I use just two threads .. UI and worker so . so no more worker threads just one .. Ok thanks if we talk about design I will never finish my app, design is work in progres and evolution in process.. Code base is quite huge and no time to any discussion just need to be sure about this now , thanks a lot .. I didnt have actually any deadlocks yet and I ended up with second version of code but sure there definitelly are problems I dont see and maybe I will rewrite it to different approach in future.

Comment: I will not follow your "why does your Stopped class have a start() method??" discussion even thou my ego surely would like to haha , a lot of opinions in my head , thanks